# Ant Builds but all of junit tests failing

Tags: xml, testing, junit, ant, antbuilder

I am new on using ant and junit. I have the following problem. My ant build.xml builds successfully but during running the junit tests the following message appears.

```
[echo] Running JUnit tests....
[mkdir] Created dir: /Users/george_ashiotis/Desktop/Coursework files-20180731/commons-validator-1.4.0/target/test-result
[junit] Running java.org.apache.commons.validator.AbstractCommonTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] Test java.org.apache.commons.validator.AbstractCommonTest FAILED
[junit] Running java.org.apache.commons.validator.AbstractNumberTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] Test java.org.apache.commons.validator.AbstractNumberTest FAILED
[junit] Running java.org.apache.commons.validator.ByteTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] Test java.org.apache.commons.validator.ByteTest FAILED
```

Note: This is happening for all of my Test files.

This is my build.xml file

```
    <!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<project name="Validator" default="dist" basedir=".">


<!--
        "Validator" component of the Apache Commons Subproject
        $Id$
        $Id$
-->


<!-- ========== Initialize Properties ===================================== -->


  <property file="build.properties"/>                <!-- Component local   -->
  <property file="../build.properties"/>             <!-- Commons local     -->
  <property file="${user.home}/build.properties"/>   <!-- User local        -->


<!-- ========== External Dependencies ===================================== -->


  <!-- The directories corresponding to your necessary dependencies -->
  <property name="commons.home"            value="../../jakarta-commons"/>
  <property name="sandbox.home"            value="../../jakarta-commons-sandbox"/>

<!-- ========== Component Declarations ==================================== -->


  <!-- The name of this component -->
  <property name="component.name"          value="validator"/>

  <!-- The primary package name of this component -->
  <property name="component.package"       value="org.apache.commons.validator"/>

  <!-- The title of this component -->
  <property name="component.title"         value="Commons Validator"/>

  <!-- The current version number of this component -->
  <property name="component.version"       value="1.4.0-SNAPSHOT"/>

  <!-- The base directory for compilation targets -->
  <property name="build.home"              value="target"/>

  <!-- The base directory for component resources -->
  <property name="resources.home"          value="src/main/resources"/>

  <!-- The base directory for distribution targets -->
  <property name="dist.home"               value="dist"/>

  <!-- The base directory for release targets -->
  <property name="release.home"            value="release" />

  <!-- The base directory for component sources -->
  <property name="source.home"             value="src/main/java"/>

  <!-- The base directory for javascript sources -->
  <property name="javascript.home"             value="src/javascript"/>

  <!-- The base directory for unit test sources -->
  <property name="test.home"               value="src/test"/>

  <!-- The base directory for example sources -->
  <property name="example.home"            value="src/example"/>

  <!-- Directory where binary release files are staged -->
  <property name="stage.bin.dir"           value="${release.home}/stage/bin"/>

  <!-- Directory where source release files are staged -->
  <property name="stage.src.dir"           value="${release.home}/stage/src"/>

  <!-- Directory where release builds are prepared for upload -->
  <property name="upload.dir"              value="${release.home}/upload"/>

  <!-- Base file name for upload files -->
  <property name="upload.file.base"        value="${component.name}-${component.version}"/>

  <!-- Download lib dir -->
  <property name="download.lib.dir"        value="lib"/>

<!-- ========== Compiler Defaults ========================================= -->


  <!-- source JDK version (should be same as maven.compile.source) -->
  <property name="compile.source"          value="1.4"/>

  <!-- target JDK version (should be same as maven.compile.target) -->
  <property name="compile.target"          value="1.4"/>

  <!-- Should Java compilations set the 'debug' compiler option? -->
  <property name="compile.debug"           value="true"/>

  <!-- Should Java compilations set the 'deprecation' compiler option? -->
  <property name="compile.deprecation"     value="false"/>

  <!-- Should Java compilations set the 'optimize' compiler option? -->
  <property name="compile.optimize"        value="true"/>

  <!-- Construct compile classpath -->
  <path id="compile.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${build.home}/classes"/>
    <pathelement location="${download.lib.dir}/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${download.lib.dir}/commons-digester-1.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${download.lib.dir}/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <path refid="downloaded.lib.classpath"/>
  </path>

  <!-- Construct compile classpath -->
  <path id="downloaded.lib.classpath">
      <pathelement location="${download.lib.dir}/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="${download.lib.dir}/commons-digester-1.8.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="${download.lib.dir}/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="${download.lib.dir}/junit-4.11.jar"/>
  </path>

<!-- ========== Test Execution Defaults =================================== -->

  <!--COURSEWORK MODIFICATION-->
  <!-- Construct unit test classpath -->
  <path id="test.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${build.home}/classes"/>
    <pathelement location="${build.home}/tests"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.11.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${xerces.jar}"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/ant-junit-1.9.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/assertj-core-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/mockito-all-1.9.5.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/pitest-1.1.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/pitest-ant-1.1.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/quickbuilder-1.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/xstream-1.4.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-collections-3.2.1-1.0.0.jar" />
    <!--<path refid="downloaded.lib.classpath"/>-->
  </path>

  <!-- Should all tests fail if one does? -->
  <property name="test.failonerror"        value="true"/>

  <!-- The test runner to execute -->
  <property name="test.runner"             value="junit.textui.TestRunner"/>

  <!-- create pitest task -->
  <taskdef name="pitest" classpathref="test.classpath" classname="org.pitest.ant.PitestTask" />

  <taskdef name="junit" classpathref="test.classpath" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask"/>


<!-- ========== Executable Targets ======================================== -->


  <target name="init"
   description="Initialize and evaluate conditionals">
    <echo message="-------- ${component.name} ${component.version} --------"/>
    <filter  token="name"                  value="${component.name}"/>
    <filter  token="package"               value="${component.package}"/>
    <filter  token="version"               value="${component.version}"/>
    <filter  token="compilesource"         value="${compile.source}"/>
    <filter  token="compiletarget"         value="${compile.target}"/>
    <available property="jsdoc.found" type="file" file="${jsdoc.home}/jsdoc.pl"/>
  </target>


  <target name="prepare" depends="init"
   description="Prepare build directory">
    <mkdir dir="${build.home}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.home}/classes"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.home}/tests"/>
  </target>


  <target name="static" depends="prepare"
   description="Copy static files to build directory">
    <tstamp/>
  </target>


  <target name="compile" depends="static" description="Compile shareable components">
      <mkdir dir="${build.home}/classes"/>
      <javac    srcdir="${source.home}"
                includeantruntime="false"
                destdir="${build.home}/classes"
                source="${compile.source}"
                target="${compile.target}"
                debug="true"
                debuglevel="source,lines"
                encoding="cp1252"
                deprecation="${compile.deprecation}"
                optimize="${compile.optimize}">
                <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
      </javac>
    <copy    todir="${build.home}/classes" filtering="on">
      <fileset dir="${source.home}"
          excludes="**/*.java"/>
    </copy>
    <copy    todir="${build.home}/classes">
      <fileset dir="${resources.home}" includes="**/*.dtd,**/*.xml"/>
    </copy>
    <copy    todir="${build.home}/classes/">
      <fileset dir="${javascript.home}"
          includes="**/*.js"/>
    </copy>
  </target>


  <target name="clean"
   description="Clean build and distribution directories">
    <delete    dir="${build.home}"/>
    <delete    dir="${dist.home}"/>
    <delete    dir="${release.home}"/>
    <delete    dir="pitReports" />
  </target>


  <target name="all" depends="clean,compile"
   description="Clean and compile all components"/>


  <target name="javadoc.init" 
   description="Initializes Javadoc directories">
    <mkdir      dir="${dist.home}"/>
    <mkdir      dir="${dist.home}/docs"/>
    <mkdir      dir="${dist.home}/docs/apidocs"/>
    <mkdir      dir="${dist.home}/docs/javascript"/>
    <mkdir      dir="${dist.home}/docs/javascript/org/apache/commons/validator/javascript/doc-files"/>
  </target>  

  <target name="javadoc.js" depends="javadoc.js.unix,javadoc.js.windows"
   description="Create Javascript Javadoc documentation">

    <copy todir="${dist.home}/docs/javascript/org/apache/commons/validator/javascript/doc-files">
      <fileset dir="${javascript.home}/org/apache/commons/validator/javascript/doc-files" includes="*.gif"/>
    </copy>

  </target>

  <target name="javadoc.js.unix" depends="javadoc.init" if="jsdoc.found"
   description="Create Javascript Javadoc documentation">
    <exec  executable="bash" failifexecutionfails="false">
         <arg line="-c 'etc/jsdoc.sh ${jsdoc.home} ${javascript.home} ${dist.home}/docs/javascript' "/>
    </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="javadoc.js.windows" depends="javadoc.init" if="jsdoc.found"
   description="Windows Create Javascript Javadoc documentation">
    <exec  executable="etc/jsdoc.bat" failifexecutionfails="false">
         <arg line="${jsdoc.home} ${javascript.home} ${dist.home}/docs/javascript"/>
    </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="javadoc" depends="compile, javadoc.js"
   description="Create component Javadoc documentation">
    <!--javadoc sourcepath="${source.home}"
                destdir="${dist.home}/docs/apidocs"
           packagenames="org.apache.commons.*"
                 author="true"
                private="true"
                version="true"
               doctitle="&lt;h1&gt;${component.title} (Version ${component.version})&lt;/h1&gt;"
            windowtitle="${component.title} (Version ${component.version})"
                 bottom="Copyright (c) 2001-2004  Apache Software Foundation"
           classpathref="compile.classpath" / -->
  </target>



  <target name="change-log" >
    <cvschangelog destfile="changelog.xml" start="${cvs.start}" />
     <style in="changelog.xml" out="changelog.html" style="${ant.home}/etc/changelog.xsl">
          <param name="title" expression="Validator ChangeLog"/>
          <param name="module" expression="commons"/>
          <param name="cvsweb" expression="http://cvs.apache.org/viewcvs/"/>
    </style>
  </target>



  <target name="dist" depends="compile,javadoc"
   description="Create binary distribution">
    <mkdir      dir="${dist.home}"/>

    <ant antfile="build-javascript.xml" target="compress">
        <property name="source.dir" value="${javascript.home}"/>
        <property name="dist.dir"   value="${dist.home}"/>
        <property name="build.dir"  value="${build.home}"/>
        <property name="final.name" value="commons-${component.name}-${component.version}"/>
    </ant>

    <copy      file="LICENSE.txt"
              todir="${dist.home}"/>
    <copy      file="NOTICE.txt"
              todir="${dist.home}"/>
    <copy      file="RELEASE-NOTES.txt"
              todir="${dist.home}"/>
    <mkdir      dir="${build.home}/classes/META-INF"/>
    <copy      file="LICENSE.txt"
             tofile="${build.home}/classes/META-INF/LICENSE.txt"/>
    <copy      file="NOTICE.txt"
             tofile="${build.home}/classes/META-INF/NOTICE.txt"/>

    <manifest file="${build.home}/MANIFEST.MF">
        <attribute name="Specification-Title"      value="${component.title}"/>
        <attribute name="Specification-Version"    value="${component.version}"/>
        <attribute name="Specification-Vendor"     value="Apache Software Foundation"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Title"     value="${component.title}"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Version"   value="${component.version}"/> 
        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor"    value="Apache Software Foundation"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor-Id" value="org.apache"/>
        <attribute name="X-Compile-Source-JDK"     value="${compile.source}"/>
        <attribute name="X-Compile-Target-JDK"     value="${compile.target}"/>
    </manifest>

    <jar    jarfile="${dist.home}/commons-${component.name}-${component.version}.jar"
            basedir="${build.home}/classes"
           manifest="${build.home}/MANIFEST.MF"/>
  </target>

<!-- ========== Unit Test Targets ========================================= -->


  <target name="compile.tests" depends="compile" description="Compile unit test cases">
      <javac    srcdir="${test.home}"
                destdir="${build.home}/tests"
                debug="true"
                debuglevel="source,lines"
                source="${compile.source}"
                target="${compile.target}"
                deprecation="${compile.deprecation}"
                includeantruntime="false"
                encoding="cp1252"
                optimize="${compile.optimize}">
                <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
      </javac>

      <copy    todir="${build.home}/tests" filtering="on">
          <fileset dir="${test.home}/resources"/>
      </copy>

  </target>


  <target name="test"  depends="compile.tests" description="Run all unit test cases">
        <echo message ="Running JUnit tests...." />
        <mkdir dir="${build.home}/test-result" />

        <junit printsummary="yes" showoutput="true">
            <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <!-- If test.entry is defined, run a single test, otherwise run all valid tests -->
            <test name="${test.entry}" todir="${build.home}/test-result" if="test.entry"/>
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${build.home}/test-result" unless="test.entry">
                <fileset dir="${test.home}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
        <!-- junitreport omitted for coursework -->
  </target>

  <!-- ========== MUTATION TESTS =========================================== -->

  <target name="pit" depends="clean,test,compile">
      <echo message="Running mutation tests ..."/>
      <pitest   pitClasspath="test.classpath"
                threads="2"
                classPath="test.classpath"
                targetTests="org.apache.commons.validator.*"
                targetClasses="org.apache.commons.validator.*"
                reportDir="pitReports"
                sourceDir="${source.home}" />
  </target>

  <!-- ========== MUTATION TESTS =========================================== -->


<!-- ========== Release Targets =========================================== -->


    <target name="release" depends="clean,dist"
    description="Construct release distribution">
        <mkdir dir="${stage.bin.dir}/${upload.file.base}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${stage.src.dir}/${upload.file.base}-src"/>
        <copy todir="${stage.bin.dir}/${upload.file.base}">
            <fileset dir="${dist.home}"/>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${stage.src.dir}/${upload.file.base}-src">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <exclude name="build.properties"/>
                <exclude name="${build.home}/**"/>
                <exclude name="${dist.home}/**"/>
                <exclude name="${build.home}/**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <mkdir dir="${upload.dir}"/>
        <zip  zipfile="${upload.dir}/${upload.file.base}.zip"
              basedir="${stage.bin.dir}"/>
        <zip  zipfile="${upload.dir}/${upload.file.base}-src.zip"
              basedir="${stage.src.dir}"/>
        <tar  tarfile="${upload.dir}/${upload.file.base}.tar"
              basedir="${stage.bin.dir}"
             longfile="gnu"/>
        <tar  tarfile="${upload.dir}/${upload.file.base}-src.tar"
              basedir="${stage.src.dir}"
             longfile="gnu"/>
        <gzip     src="${upload.dir}/${upload.file.base}.tar"
              zipfile="${upload.dir}/${upload.file.base}.tar.gz"/>
        <gzip     src="${upload.dir}/${upload.file.base}-src.tar"
              zipfile="${upload.dir}/${upload.file.base}-src.tar.gz"/>
    </target>


</project>
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Any help is appreciated

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the same question over to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VALIDATOR-443. You can also find the answer there.

So basically the problem is that the ant build has been dropped from the project 1.4.0. and the suggested me to use the latest release and build it with maven.

I hope this helps.